# Eclipse RCP persistence framework integration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

I am developing an Eclipse application, using the latest version of Eclipse RCP and RAP 2022-12.
I have a target platform, a product file, a complete Maven/Tycho build system working with unit and integration test.

My need now is to persist to a DB (my preference here is MongoDB) a simple POJO class, for example:

```java
/**
 * The logged user.
 */
public class User implements IMASUser {

    /**
     * Developer user name
     */
    public static final String DEVELOPER_USER_NAME = "developer"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DB_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(CommonConstants.DB_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN);

    private int m_id;
    private String m_username;
    private String m_password;
    private String m_name;
    private String m_surname;
    private String m_domainID;
    private String m_office;
    private String m_blockCode;
    private String m_eMail;
    private AccessLevel m_accessLevel;
    private boolean m_isBeta; // Access to beta program
    private boolean m_isActive; // Currently working (hired and actively developing)

    private Date m_loginDate;
    private Date m_lastLoginDate;
......
```

What is the most "common" and easy way to integrate a persistence framework into an Eclipse RCP application?

In a standard Java app I would try Hibernate or Spring Boot but here the integration in the OSGi environment is somehow problematic.

I tried to integrate:

- Spring Boot JPA
- Hibernate
- Eclipselink

adding the dependencies to the target platform.

**All of those have problems runtime discovering the needed service and classes.**
For sure I'm missing some experience in Eclipse/RCP/OSGi.

Can you share some of your experience (if any), I can't find any *up to date* documentation.
Thank you!

Comment: "What is the most "common" and easy way to integrate a persistence framework into an Eclipse RCP application?" I always used JDBC, but I always linked to a relational database.

Comment: Look at how others are doing it, e.g. [Eclipse Jubula](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.jubula).

Comment: For EclipseLink, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation which describes setting up JPA within OSGI. For Mongo/NoSQL db support, you'll want the noSQL osgi bundle as well: org.eclipse.persistence.nosql

Comment: Thank you! Very useful advises. 
What about these Spring boot OSGi implementation: https://aries.apache.org/documentation/index.html or https://karaf.apache.org/ 

For now  I  don't need a complete web service framework, only persistence, but since I need to integrate something it might be convenient to have a whole framework functionality. It depends on how "hard" is the integration..